# Why do I receive a KeyError when I write my data to csv? What can be done to create exception error handling?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Im new to python and trying to understand error handling

My script-

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
import time

def process_data(json_data, output_path):

    print(f"Processing: {output_path.stem}")

    cols = ["transcript", "confidence"]

    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata, columns = cols)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get("speaker_labels")).drop(["final", "confidence"], axis=1)


    # test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
    test3 = pd.merge(df0, df1, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

However, I receive an error-

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-b2f6a9044995>", line 150, in <module>
    main()

  File "<ipython-input-5-b2f6a9044995>", line 141, in main
    process_data(*pkg)

  File "<ipython-input-5-b2f6a9044995>", line 59, in process_data
    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

  File "<ipython-input-5-b2f6a9044995>", line 59, in <listcomp>
    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

KeyError: 'confidence'
```

What do I need to change or add in my code to avoid this error? Or just skip this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because one or more records in the `r.get("alternatives")` does not have `confidence` key - hence the `KeyError: 'confidence'` exception.

To fix it, provide a default value when retrieving the key, e.g. `0` or `None`, by using `get` method instead of `[]`.

```
dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t.get(cols[1], None)]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately,It says invalid syntax when i replace my line with yours